# How do I start from Super User, and zero in on a particular Super User user?

Tags: support

There is a user in Superuser named "Rounit". This link shows a contribution of his in Superuser:

[Indirect Function in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1578963/indirect-function-in-excel)

Now if I try to find him in Superuser site, I first go to:

https://superuser.com/

then on left panel I click on "Users". Then I choos "All" at the right side. Then I put the name "Rounit" inside the search box and hit the key "ENTER". Nothing comes up! Can anybody explain this?

Comment: Just click on his username to "find" him.

Answer (score 1):

Rounit is an unregistered user. You can see this in the user profile.

[image: Snapshot of Rounit's user profile]

Unregistered users are no listed in the [Users](https://superuser.com/users) lists.

References

- [Is there a way to sift through a list of unregistered users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/49764/289691)
- [How can I find/search for an unregistered user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134415/289691)

Related

- [Display list of Unregistered users by Reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192191/289691)